# Renaming a column in a materialized view with an unknown name

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, materialized-view

I have a materialized view with an unknown column name, and I need to give that column a name. I can't just recreate the view because it took a long time to create.

```
dba=# \d temp_name_relationships;                                                    
Materialized view "temp_name_relationships"
  Column  |       Type       | Modifiers
----------+------------------+-----------
 id       | bigint           |
 source   | integer          |
 name1    | text             |
 name2    | text             |
 ?column? | double precision |
 sum      | bigint           |
```

That `?column?` in there is the offender. How do I rename it? I've tried:

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW temp_name_relationships RENAME COLUMN ?column? TO score;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "?"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just remembered you can quote table names, and I guess this works to escape the question marks.

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW temp_name_relationships RENAME COLUMN "?column?" TO score;
```

Comment: No need to guess. Do it and you'll see it works.

Comment: can you mark as chosen?